# How to read help() from QGIS classes

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to copy a shapefile and give it a new name in QGIS python console, I am trying to use the QgsVectorFileWriter class' writeAsVectorFormat method

```
    writeAsVectorFormat(...)
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(QgsVectorLayer, QString, 
    QString, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QString driverName="ESRI
    Shapefile", bool onlySelected=False, QString errorMessage=None,
    QStringList datasourceOptions=QStringList(), QStringList 
    layerOptions=QStringList(), bool skipAttributeCreation=False, 
    QString newFilename=None, QgsVectorFileWriter.SymbologyExport 
    symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.NoSymbology, float 
    symbologyScale=1, QgsRectangle filterExtent=None) -> 
    QgsVectorFileWriter.WriterError
```

I am unable to determine what the QString arguments (arguments 2 & 3) are supposed to be..I get that they are strings, but strings of what?? Is there a resource I could go to that would give more help than this? I am just trying to take a shapefile, copy it and give it a new name, is this the best way?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet are the API docs, in this case http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#ac25d02c9ad8bfe6113ba7a06a981a447 and the [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/).

Comment: @rickdebbout - Don't forget to accept answers which have solved your problems by clicking the green faded tick on the left-hand side =)